# How do I specify current timestamp when importing a delimited file using the DB2 import facility

Tags: db2

I am using the DB2 `import` command and would to import a delimited file.  I would like to specify `current timestamp` in one of the fields in the file, but I can't find a way to specify it.  With or without quotes, the rows are all rejected for containing text rather than a valid timestamp.  Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Add your SQL code and the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide any details about your import process, so I'm assuming you use the `IMPORT` command. `IMPORT` does not expects any expressions in the input file, it treats all input values as literals. Subsequently you cannot reference special register variables in the input file.

The [`INGEST` command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0057198.html), however, allows you to use expressions in the SQL statement, e.g.

```
INGEST FROM FILE <source_file> 
   FORMAT DELIMITED 
   (
      $field1 INTEGER EXTERNAL,
      $filler DATE 'mm/dd/yyyy',
      $field3 CHAR(32)
   )
   INSERT INTO <table-name> 
      VALUES($field1, CURRENT TIMESTAMP, $field3);
```

Comment: That's what I needed.  Thanks for your help.